# lm_robust() gives different results with numeric predictor converted to factor than with factor predictor

Tags: r, stata, r-factor

I have this data with numerical values (I transformed values to numeric before use in R)

| P | T | Gender | Y | C | V1 | V2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 1 |

I build this model in order get the same result as Stata

```
model1<-lm_robust(P~factor(A)+factor(V)+factor(Y)+factor(Gender)+factor(T),
se_type="stata",cluster=R_ID,data=numericdata)
```

This the summary of the model1:

```
summary(model1) 
Call: 
lm_robust(formula = P~factor(A)+factor(V)+factor(Y)+factor(Gender)+factor), 
    data = numericdata, clusters = R_ID, se_type = "stata")


Standard error type:  stata 

Coefficients:
** terms **            Estimate Std. Error t value   Pr(>|t|) CI Lower CI Upper   DF
(Intercept)             3.96412    0.08955  44.268 1.012e-269  3.78846  4.13978 1421
factor(V1)1             0.51356    0.07811   6.575  6.808e-11  0.36035  0.66678 1421
factor(V2)1             0.24071    0.05249   4.586  4.923e-06  0.13774  0.34368 1421
factor(A)2             -0.82342    0.05159 -15.960  7.128e-53 -0.92462 -0.72221 1421
factor(A)3             -1.27615    0.06896 -18.506  1.129e-68 -1.41142 -1.14088 1421
factor(A)4             -2.24977    0.06845 -32.867 1.097e-176 -2.38405 -2.11550 1421
factor(A)5             -2.51676    0.09609 -26.190 1.078e-123 -2.70526 -2.32825 1421
factor(Y)1             -0.06641    0.03974  -1.671  9.497e-02 -0.14437  0.01156 1421
factor(Gender)1         0.04625    0.04095   1.130  2.589e-01 -0.03407  0.12657 1421
factor(T)1              0.08457    0.03947   2.143  3.230e-02  0.00715  0.16200 1421

Multiple R-squared:  0.4286 ,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.4274 
F-statistic: 362.2 on 9 and 1421 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

but when I use this data I don't find the same results by using this:

| P | T | Gender | Y | C | V1 | V2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P4 | T0 | Male | Y0 | C2 | V1 | V0 |
| P4 | T1 | Male | Y0 | C2 | V0 | V0 |
| P3 | T1 | Female | Y0 | C5 | V1 | V0 |
| P4 | T1 | Male | Y1 | C3 | V0 | V0 |
| P5 | T1 | Female | Y0 | C2 | V1 | V1 |
| P2 | T0 | Female | Y1 | C3 | V0 | V1 |
| P1 | T1 | Female | Y0 | C2 | V1 | V1 |
| P4 | T1 | Male | Y1 | C4 | V1 | V0 |
| P3 | T1 | Female | Y0 | C3 | V0 | V0 |
| P5 | T0 | Male | Y1 | C4 | V0 | V1 |
| P4 | T1 | Male | Y1 | C4 | V1 | V1 |
| P1 | T0 | Female | Y1 | C2 | V0 | V0 |
| P5 | T0 | Female | Y0 | C3 | V1 | V1 |
| P2 | T1 | Male | Y1 | C1 | V1 | V0 |
| P5 | T1 | Female | Y0 | C1 | V1 | V1 |
| P3 | T1 | Female | Y1 | C5 | V1 | V1 |

```
model2 <-lm_robust(P\~factor(A)+factor(V)+factor(Y)+factor(Gender)+factor(T),
se_type="stata",cluster=R_ID,data=factordata)
```

this data with factor values:

```
Call:
lm_robust(formula = P~factor(A)+factor(V)+factor(Y)+factor(Gender)+factor), 
    data = factordata, clusters = R_ID, se_type = "stata")

Standard error type:  stata 

Coefficients:
** terms **                           Estimate Std. Error  t value   Pr(>|t|)   CI Lower CI Upper   DF
(Intercept)                           2.577930    0.06344 40.63280 3.656e-240  2.4534750  2.70239 1421
factor(V1)V0                          0.167508    0.07481  2.23926  2.529e-02  0.0207677  0.31425 1421
factor(V2)V0                           0.051982    0.04608  1.12799  2.595e-01 -0.0384174  0.14238 1421
factor(A)A3                           0.445087    0.07456  5.96934  3.004e-09  0.2988231  0.59135 1421
factor(A)A2                           1.022906    0.07138 14.33071  1.317e-43  0.8828875  1.16293 1421
factor(A)A1                           0.819211    0.06458 12.68531  5.215e-35  0.6925296  0.94589 1421
factor(A)A5                           1.608496    0.09163 17.55468  1.360e-62  1.4287555  1.78824 1421
factor(Y)A0                           0.076069    0.03841  1.98062  4.783e-02  0.0007291  0.15141 1421
factor(Woman)Male                     0.064806    0.04232  1.53117  1.259e-01 -0.0182191  0.14783 1421
factor(T)T0                           0.001391    0.03769  0.03689  9.706e-01 -0.0725421  0.07532 1421

Multiple R-squared:  0.1921 ,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.1904 
F-statistic: 93.72 on 9 and 1421 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

The results aren't the same (intercept, R-squared, Estimate...), the first result is what I get in Stata and is what I want.

I want to find the same result of `model1` but  with the terms (`factor(V1)V0`, `factor(V2)V0`....) of `model2`.

Comment: You must tell us in which package is `lm_robust`!

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because your factors in `factordata` have different level orders than the default used for `numericdata`. e.g., your `model1` output implies that `0` is the reference group for `numericdata$V1`, which is as expected since it's the first value in `sort(unique(numericadata$V1)`. The equivalent value in `factordata$V1` would be `V0`, but the `model2` output implies that `V1` is the reference group.

You can confirm this by running

```r
levels(factor(numericdata$V1))
# I predict this will show "0" "1"

levels(factor(factordata$V1))
# I predict this will show "V1" "V0"
```

You can fix it using

```r
# specify order of levels...
levels(factordata$V1) <- c("V0", "V1")

# ...or use "default" order
levels(factordata$V1) <- sort(unique(factordata$V1))
```

Obviously, you would need to check and relevel all your predictors in the same way.